# Rep capped at 190 instead of 200

Tags: support, reputation

I noticed that my daily rep counter got stuck at 190 instead of the usual 200 cap.

[image: rep overview]

I still get upvotes, but no rep.
I tagged it as a bug, but maybe there's another explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had [an answer which was deleted](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18783/multiple-pulses-from-single-button-press/18785#18785), but it got an upvote. As such, the system still expects that you have +10 from it, but it isn't reflected properly on your displayed reputation or your profile page.

By going to `https://electronics.stackexchange.com/reputation`, you can view an accurate audit of your reputation on the site. This is accurate by excluding the reputation from deleted posts and votes, which otherwise are not reflected in your denormalized display value. You can set your reputation to this correct value by hitting the "recalculate" button located at the bottom of that page. This should also serve to correct today's reputation totals to give you the proper +200, but I recommend waiting until the end of the day so as to ensure all changes for the day (up and down) have settled.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about the deleted answer.